# npm run start in plutus-playground-client creating npm errors

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

edit...I was able to get the plutus-playground-client working by using --force.  How do I fix the monaco-editor dependency errors so I don't need to force it? Or do I even need to worry about it?

I am getting errors when trying to start the plutus-playground-client.

The interpreter is ready when I enter the command `GC_DONT_GC=1 plutus-playground-server` in the plutus-playground-server directory

When I enter the command `GC_DONT_GC=1 npm run start` in the plutus-playground-client directory I get a bunch of npm ERR! saying something about problems with monaco-editor

I am using an M1 macbook with Monterey V12.4

Going through Plutus Pioneer program 3rd iteration.  Git checkout week01.

I notice now when I try to build the plutus-playground-client I get the same errors as when I try to `npm run start` in the plutus-playground client directory.

The errors I'm getting are...

```
[nix-shell:~/plutus-apps]$ cd plutus-playground-client
GC_DONT_GC=1 npm run start

> plutus-playground-client@1.0.0 start
> plutus-playground-generate-purs && npm install && npm run install:spago && npm run build:webpack:dev

[Info] Running: (Nothing,PSGenerator {_outputDir = "generated"})
The following purescript packages are needed by the generated code:

  - plutus-playground-client
  - purescript-argonaut-codecs
  - purescript-either
  - purescript-enums
  - purescript-lists
  - purescript-maybe
  - purescript-newtype
  - purescript-ordered-collections
  - purescript-prelude
  - purescript-profunctor-lenses
  - purescript-tuples
  - web-common

Successfully created your PureScript modules!

Successfully created your servant API purescript functions!
Please make sure you have purescript-servant-support and purescript-bridge-json-helpers installed

Done: generated
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: monaco-emacs@0.2.2
npm ERR! Found: monaco-editor@0.21.3
npm ERR! node_modules/monaco-editor
npm ERR!   monaco-editor@"^0.21.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer monaco-editor@"0.21.x" from monaco-editor-webpack-plugin@2.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     monaco-editor-webpack-plugin@"^2.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (monaco-vim)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer monaco-editor@"^0.14.0 || ^0.15.0 || ^0.16.0 || ^0.17.0 || ^0.18.0 || ^0.19.3 || ^0.20.0" from monaco-emacs@0.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/monaco-emacs
npm ERR!   monaco-emacs@"^0.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: monaco-editor@0.20.0
npm ERR! node_modules/monaco-editor
npm ERR!   peer monaco-editor@"^0.14.0 || ^0.15.0 || ^0.16.0 || ^0.17.0 || ^0.18.0 || ^0.19.3 || ^0.20.0" from monaco-emacs@0.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/monaco-emacs
npm ERR!     monaco-emacs@"^0.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/tamio/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/tamio/.npm/_logs/2022-08-04T13_36_55_265Z-debug-0.log

[nix-shell:~/plutus-apps/plutus-playground-client]$
```